# How do I make a reference property to a model defined later?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a class A that has a `db.ReferenceProperty` referencing a type of entity that is defined later in the file. How do I refer to B from A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't move B above A, then you can use the following workaround:

```
foo = db.ReferenceProperty(reference_class=db.Model)
```

This essentially allows you to reference any class that extends db.Model. You can add validation logic if needed.

You also cannot use the collection_name attribute to back reference A from B.